# Rails server not running. No such file or directory @ dir_s_mkdir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle

I followed GoRails tutorial and installed rbenv.
After struggling a little with gems, came across this problem:

```
Bundle complete! 49 Gemfile dependencies, 124 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
Diegos-MacBook-Pro:used_products diiru$ which rails
/Users/diiru/.rbenv/shims/rails
 Diegos-MacBook-Pro:used_products diiru$
/Users/diiru/.rbenv/shims/rails server
```

Comment: Please add to your question the code from `Users/diiru/Desktop/Try/used_products/config/application.rb` file

Comment: @VAD Updated ! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to create directory `/Users/diiru/Desktop/Try/used_products/log/webpay`

Comment: That was only an error when I copies the code to StackOverflow, the original code is properly written. Any ideas of why this error could be affecting everything ?

Comment: Yes ! That was it, just figured it out minutes ago. Thanks for the help anyway !